# Failed to check FreeRDP file descriptor

Tags: remote, remote-desktop, freerdp

Using `xfreerdp` version 1.1.0:

```
oshiro@debian:~$ xfreerdp --version
This is FreeRDP version 1.1.0-beta1 (git n/a)
oshiro@debian:~$
```

I am getting the following error message:

```
oshiro@debian:~$ sudo xfreerdp /v:farm.company.com /d:company.com /g:rds.company.com /u:rds_username /p:rds_password /f
connected to rds.company.com:443
connected to rds.company.com:443
TS Gateway Connection Success
Got stub length 4 with flags 3 and callid 7
...
Got stub length 4 with flags 3 and callid 192
WaitForSingleObject: unknown handle type 6715497
connected to rds.company.com:443
connected to rds.company.com:443
TS Gateway Connection Success
Got stub length 4 with flags 3 and callid 7
...
Got stub length 4 with flags 3 and callid 22
Failed to check FreeRDP file descriptor
Got stub length 4 with flags 2 and callid 6
WaitForSingleObject: unknown handle type 0
oshiro@debian:~$
```

Anyone know how to stop the following error message coming up?

```
Failed to check FreeRDP file descriptor
Got stub length 4 with flags 2 and callid 6
WaitForSingleObject: unknown handle type 0
```

I have tried version xfreerdp 1.2.0, but that doesn't even load an rds window.  xfreerdp 1.1.0 at-least shows the rds window for a short while until the above message is shown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not an actual solution but these issues in the XFreeRDP issue tracker look to be the same problem (or related) you're running into.

- [freerdp crashing sporadically with connection to gateway #1473](https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/issues/1473)
- [TS Gateway connection problem, Unexpected RTS PDU: Expected CONN/C2 #1505](https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/issues/1505)
- [TS Gateway Support #386](https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/issues/386)

*excerpt*

```
Got stub length 4 with flags 3 and callid 27309
Got stub length 4 with flags 0 and callid 6
WARNING: invalid packet signature
Got stub length 4 with flags 3 and callid 27310
WARNING: invalid packet signature
Failed to check FreeRDP file descriptor
Got stub length 4 with flags 3 and callid 27311
Got stub length 4 with flags 2 and callid 6
WaitForSingleObject: pthread_join failure: [3] No such process
```

I think with all these XFreeRDP issues you've been running into I'd push them upstream to the project's issue tracker. Seems like these are legitimate bugs that should/could be resolved by the actual developers.